ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf' with sudo apt-get install
I am trying to download flask-wtf systemwide with
sudo apt-get install python3-flask-wtf
but nothing was found also
sudo apt-get install python3-python-flask-wtf
as with jwt extended was also not found does any of you know the
sudo apt-get install python3-packagename of flask_wtf?
I tried to download flask-wtf with the
sudo apt-get install python3-flask-wtf
command, but could not download. I knew that for flask-jwt-extended you needed to append python to the command like
sudo apt-get install python3-python-flask-jwt-extended

Why are you trying to use use apt-get instead of pip ?

If you don't know a package's name, you can search for it using apt-cache search --names-only flask wtf or your distro's package repository search page (Debian, Ubuntu). You may also want to make sure your package lists are up-to-date by running sudo apt-get update.

I personally would use sudo pip install flask but pip doesn’t like it that much. It throws warnings at you.
